# Google analytics tracking code not receiving test traffic

Tags: google-analytics

Are the curly brackets around `customeUSERID` on line 2 correct? In google documentation, the curly brackets are left on.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'userId', {{customUSERID}});
ga('set', 'dimension3', customUSERID);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

**UPDATE**

My google analytics tracking code isn't working, is it because of the curly braces

Is it possible to have to have two 'sets' in the same tracking code

Comment: Your problem is not two set of curly braces, your problem is that the curly braces are placeholders that need to filled in with values (and the values must not have curly braces around them). And since the values are string you need quotes.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff, so If I add quotes around customUSERID, this will work? {{"customUSERID"}}

Comment: I have a variable named customUSERID, should this be the coded the same as dimension3?

Comment: "I have a variable named customUSERID, should this be the coded the same as dimension3" > Yes